# How can I make Inkscape run fast, without using these tricks?

Tags: 12.04, inkscape

Inkscape was very slow on my PC, But fortunately, I found a solution. Removing `liboverlay*` packages and overlay-scrollbar helps. But I don't want to use this tricks to speedup Inkscape.

So, **My question is**: How can I make Inkscape faster without removing these components?

Answer (score 6):

This might not be the kind of answer you are looking for, but one thing you can do to make Inkscape feel faster is to change the display mode from "Normal" to "No Filters". Obviously you don't see the filters in that mode, but the preview renders a lot faster.

The option is in the menu View > Display mode > No Filters